# Is this small perpendicular wall load bearing to the structure?

Tags: framing, structural, load-bearing

Curious to if this wall is load bearing or not. The ceiling joist span 16ft and the only interior wall that runs perpendicular is this small one here. All other interior walls run parallel and don't even land under a joist. Also added roof structure

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unless there is a beam on each side of the wall providing support for the other roof trusses, I do not think so.  There is no extra heavy weight above the wall?  Usually load bearing walls will go from end to end, or short walls with beams/headers in between.  But a structural engineer on sight will give the best advice.

Answer (score 2):

If the bottom chord of the roof system is really 2x4s, they rafter ties not joists and not meant to support weight so any interior walls are definitively not load-bearing.

My first thought was that if those were joists, a tiny amount of cost could be saved by using smaller ones over the perpendicular wall or by using off-cuts and not continuous over that wall.   But if they are 2x4 rafter ties, none of that is likely at all.

Comment: yup, looks like a garage-type structure, 16ft 2x4s are ties not joists. 2x8 is minimum for 16ft span